# Vue leaflet for vue3 not rendering map

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

I use `"@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet": "^0.6.1"` to show a map on my Laravel Vue project.

But there is a something weird. The map is not fully rendered.

My component code:

```
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-map" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-map-tab" style="height:500px;">
            <l-map ref="map" :zoom="13" :center="[-3.6968561, 103.4372309]">
                <l-tile-layer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" layer-type="base" name="OpenStreetMap">
                </l-tile-layer>
            </l-map>
        </div>
```

setup code:

```
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"
import { LMap, LTileLayer, LMarker } from '@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet'

export default {
    components: {
        LMap,
        LTileLayer,
        LMarker
    },
```

The result map is like this screenshot (not fully load).
[image]

But if i right click on page, and choose inspect element on browser or resize the browser window, the map will suddenly become full loaded, and there is no error log in console.

After open inspect element:
[image]

UPDATE:
I have try to use original leaflet, and follow the tutorial. But the result is also same. For first load the map is not fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with run invalidateSize before setView the map

```
setTimeout(function () {
                myMap.invalidateSize()
                myMap.setView([51.505, -0.09], 13)
            }, 1000)
```